# factory_girl create vs build and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I am having some trouble with factory_girl's associations:

```
Factory.define :account do |f|
  f.sequence(:email) {|n| "john#{n}@example.com" }
  f.password "secret"
  f.confirmed_at 2.days.ago.to_s(:db)
  f.name "John Doe"
  f.seller false
  f.admin false
end

Factory.define :request do |f|
  f.association :account
  f.message 'Test message.'
end
```

And here's the problem:

When I do a = Factory(:request), a.account => nil but when I do a = Factory.build(:request), a.account is correct.

Any idea why this might be ?

Thanks

Comment: No validation problem here? What if you do a.errors after the creation?

Comment: there are no validation errors on the Request mock... it gets saved but with no account_id, which makes me wonder if there are validation errors on request.account, any way I can check for that ?

Comment: I am also not sure why the SQL looks like this before the Request is created "SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`email` IS NULL LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

Factory(:request) calls for default strategy, did you changed that somewhere?

Comment: That's not an answer, just a comment

Comment: factory_girl gives you the chance to override the default strategy used to build objects. In any case looking at the above code, are you sure you aren't missing the password_confirmation field too?

Comment: I just realized I was setting the association in the model in a before_save callback... ugh... thanks for help tho